# Add input field by radio option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Im trying to show/add the field 'area_outros_descricao' when the radio button is selected with value 4. What im doing wrong ?

```
form do |f|
     ...
     ...

     f.input :tipo_proposta, label: 'Proposta do Projeto', as: :radio, collection: {'Fechada' => 1, 'Pontual'=> 2, 'Emergencial' => 3, 'Outros' => 4}

     if f.object.tipo_proposta == 4
         f.input :area_outros_descricao, label: 'Descrição'
     end

     ...
     ...

end
f.actions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **`JavaScript`**:

Here is an example to **add Input fields** on *Radio button* selected..

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

}
```

### [Demo1 :](http://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/16/)

Another Example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
```

### [Demo2:](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/tT48f/43/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery on client side to show or hide the input.